# Solving Lambert style equation

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, inverse-function, lambert-w, lagrange-inversion

I am looking for the values $ x \in R $ which satisfy the following equation :

$ e^{-\alpha x} = \frac{a}{x - c} $

Where $ \alpha $, $ a $ and $ c $ are real valued constants.

If $ c = 0 $, we get $ x = - \frac{W(-a \alpha)}{\alpha} $, where $ W$ denotes the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but with $ c \neq 0 $ I don't see an obvious solution.

Otherwise, could I find an approximate solution with numerical methods in limited time ? (my system needs to be running in real time)

Comment: If you define $y=x-c$ you will get $e^{-\alpha c}e^{-\alpha y}={a\over y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what @user721481  suggested, you should arrive at
$$x=c-\frac{W\left(-a \alpha  e^{\alpha  c}\right)}{\alpha }$$

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:
$$
e^{-\alpha x} = \frac{a}{x-c}
\\
(x-c)e^{-\alpha x} = a
\\
(x-c)e^{-\alpha x} e^{\alpha c} = a e^{\alpha c}
\\
(x-c)e^{-\alpha (x-c)} = a e^{\alpha c}
\\
-\alpha(x-c)e^{-\alpha (x-c)} = -a\alpha e^{\alpha c}
\\
-\alpha(x-c) = W(-a\alpha e^{\alpha c})
\\
x-c = -\frac{W(-a\alpha e^{\alpha c})}{\alpha}
\\
x = c-\frac{W(-a\alpha e^{\alpha c})}{\alpha}
$$